# Unable to type when ajax call is running in background

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a website where i have set_timeout to call ajax after some interval 
when ever ajax call is running in background i am unable to type a single word .
here is my code ..

I have several fields like textarea and inputs but whenever ajax call runs in background i am unable to type . i have also disabled trigger function but in case any ajax call runs i am facing same issue .

```
var Trigger = function(){
    var jsondata={action:"trigger"};
  CallAjaxPW('', jsondata, 'ajax_trigger.php', function callBack(data) {
                              var parsed_data=  jQuery.parseJSON(data);

                                if (parsed_data)
                                   {

                                      if(parsed_data[0].messages>0){

                                          if($('#msg1').css('display')=='none'){
                                            $('#msg1').show();
                                            $('#msg1').text(parsed_data[0].messages);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                           $('#msg1').text(parsed_data[0].messages); 
                                        }

                                      }
                                     else if(parsed_data[0].messages==0){
                                           $('#msg1').hide();
                                        }
                                       if(parsed_data[0].friend_requests>0){

                                          if($('#friend_requests').css('display')=='none'){
                                            $('#friend_requests').show();
                                            $('#friend_requests').text(parsed_data[0].friend_requests);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                           $('#friend_requests').text(parsed_data[0].friend_requests); 
                                        }

                                      }
                                        else if(parsed_data[0].friend_requests==0){
                                           $('#friend_requests').hide();
                                        }
                                      if(parsed_data[0].notifications>0){

                                          if($('#noti').css('display')=='none'){
                                            $('#noti').show();
                                            $('#noti').text(parsed_data[0].notifications);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                           $('#noti').text(parsed_data[0].notifications); 
                                        }

                                      }

                               }
                                else
                                   {
                                   }
                              });
                          };

/////////////////////////////Calling Trigger////////////////////////////////////

setInterval(Trigger,10000);


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



function CallAjaxPW(form, postData, url, callBack, b, c)
{
   var sendData;
   if (form == "")
   {
      sendData = postData;
   }
   else if (postData == "")
   {
      sendData = $(form).serialize();
   }
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      cache: false,
      async: true,
      beforeSend: b,
      complete: c,
      data: sendData,
      success: callBack,
      error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
      }


   });

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem let me know if you can resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this below to trigger your code every x second. Otherwise, new calls are made even if the last ones arent finished. And (im not shure about this statement) javascript likes setTimeout more than setInterval, which gives a little performance boost.

```
function trigger() {
    //working stuff here in sync

    //call set timeout AFTER ajax request has completed
    setTimeout(function() {
        trigger();
    }, 1000);
}
```